# MVC3 Razor - using viewbag in controller and view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I am trying to create dynamic properties for my viewbag based on an if/else condition in my controller. What the viewbag displays will depend on my logic in the controller. In my view I try to call my viewbag with razor syntax but nothing renders to the page.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditUser(vw_UserManager_Model edituser)
        {
            UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model model = edituser; 
            int outcome = 0;
                outcome = UserManager.DAL.EditUser(model);
                if (outcome == 1)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Successfully edited user" + model.UserName;
                    ViewBag.Description = "Look below for full details.";
                    //ViewData["Message"] = "Successfully edited user" + model.UserName;
                    return RedirectToAction("showSuccess", model);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Failure";
                    return RedirectToAction("showFailure", model);
                }
        }

#region successErrorHandling
        public ActionResult showError(List<string> ErrorMessage)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage[0];
            return View("ErrorMessageView");
        }

        public ActionResult showSuccess(vw_UserManager_Model model)
        {

            return View("SuccessMessageeView", model);
        }
```

I set two properties for viewbag, message and description. I do a redirect if successful or failure.

```
@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<br />
<h4>@ViewBag.Description</h4>
<h2>
    SuccessMessageeView</h2>
<br />
User Created:
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul>
        <li> <b>@Html.Label("Username:  ")</b>@Model.UserName</li>
        <li> <b>@Html.Label("Salutation:  ")</b>@Model.salutation</li>
        <li> <b>@Html.Label("Firstname:  ")</b>@Model.firstname</li>
        <li>  <b>@Html.Label("Lastname:  ")</b>@Model.lastname</li>
        <li> <b>@Html.Label("Email:  ")</b>@Model.email</li>
        <li> <b>@Html.Label("Group name:  ")</b>@Model.group_name</li>
        <li> <b>@Html.Label("Is active:  ")</b>@Model.isactive</li>
    </ul>
}
```

In my view I then call my viewbag but it doesn't render. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: You lose the state of the ViewBag with the redirect. Please post your showSuccess and showFailure actions (and the name of your view) so we can suggest a solution.

Comment: @Hari ok I will edit my post.

Comment: I think I put my viewbag in the wrong ActionResult method. :(

Comment: You can use TempData instead of this.. It really works you can refer this: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/9KHW190712-ViewData-vs-ViewBag-vs-TempData-objects-in-mvc3-razor.html

Answer (score 5):

As Hari mentioned, because you are redirecting, you lose the viewbag data. If you want to persist data between requests, [use TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) instead. [This blog](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/) describes what TempData should be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use ViewBag if it can be put in the view model.
Viewbag should only be used to work with him on the same page on the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col ">
                @{
                    string first = "DEPOSITED PAYMENTS";
                    string second = "PENDING FOR CLEARING";
                    string third = "PRINT C.R./ P.R";
                    string fourth = "CUSTOMER PAYMENTS CREDITS";
                    string descript = String.Format("{0} \n {1} \n {2} \n {3}", first, second, third, fourth);
                    
                        }
                   <a href="@Url.Action("Search", "PurchaseOrder", new { type = 2 })" class="text-decoration-none">
                            @Html.Action("_DashbordBoxInfo", "Dashboard", new { description = descript, status = 1, deptCode = "Sedam3" })
                   </a>
             </div>
```

I was trying to format a string in viewbag.description which I want line by line per word the \n is not working and when I render it it reads entire value as 1 sentence inline i try to control in my parent card but it did not work any help?